# Why are so many chrome process running in my os?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, headless

No chrome opened .

```
ps aux|grep chrome | grep headless |wc -l
71
```

I can see there are 71 chrome process with headless running now.

```
debian   28661  0.0  1.2 329728 47120 pts/1    Sl   22:37   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle=17139464576301491672,838149495171029912,131072 --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --enable-logging --headless --log-level=0 --ozone-platform=headless --headless --enable-crash-reporter --gpu-preferences=QAAAAAAAAAAgAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAA --use-gl=swiftshader-webgl --override-use-software-gl-for-tests --enable-logging --log-level=0 --shared-files
debian   28662  0.0  1.2 313136 49928 pts/1    Sl   22:37   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=utility --utility-sub-type=network.mojom.NetworkService --field-trial-handle=17139464576301491672,838149495171029912,131072 --lang=en-GB --service-sandbox-type=network --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --enable-logging --log-level=0 --use-gl=swiftshader-webgl --headless --enable-crash-reporter --enable-logging --log-level=0 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
debian   28664  0.0  1.7 4558860 67900 pts/1   Sl   22:37   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --enable-automation --enable-logging --log-level=0 --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --allow-pre-commit-input --ozone-platform=headless --field-trial-handle=17139464576301491672,838149495171029912,131072 --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --lang=en-GB --headless --enable-crash-reporter --lang=en-GB --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=4 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100
```

I have already killed these processes with :

```
ps aux|grep chrome |grep headless | tr -s " " |cut -d " " -f 2 |xargs -i sudo kill {}
```

About three hours later,chrome processes fulled my memory again.

Was my pc attacked by someone?

Comment: Are there any extensions in (that copy of) Chrome that might be crypto-miners or some other malware?

Comment: Open Chrome and look at its task manager (Shift-Esc).

Comment: Google chrome does this. Google chrome seems to be a really heavy operating system.